# RetrieveEntityRequest for multiple entities at once?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm using the RetrieveEntityRequest to get an entity's attributes' metadata:

```
RetrieveEntityRequest entityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
    LogicalName = joinedEntityName.Value,
};

RetrieveEntityResponse joinedEntityMetadata = (RetrieveEntityResponse)_service.Execute(entityRequest);
```

Now, consider I need to execute this request for multiple entities. Is it possible to do this in one execution (maybe not with RetrieveEntityRequest), instead of one request for each entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `RetrieveEntityRequest`. However, you can do a [`RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrievemetadatachangesrequest.aspx) to get what you want. It's misleadingly named for your purposes, but if you don't provide a `ClientVersionStamp` property, it will simply retrieve everything you've specified in the `Query` property.

Here's a simple example where you'd retrieve the metadata for account and contact, and only retrieve the `LogicalName` and `DisplayName` properties:

```
var customFilterExpression = new[]
{
    new MetadataConditionExpression("LogicalName", MetadataConditionOperator.Equals, "account"),
    new MetadataConditionExpression("LogicalName", MetadataConditionOperator.Equals, "contact")
};
var customFilter = new MetadataFilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);
customFilter.Conditions.AddRange(customFilterExpression);

var entityProperties = new MetadataPropertiesExpression
{
    AllProperties = false
};
entityProperties.PropertyNames.AddRange("LogicalName", "DisplayName");

var request = new RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest
{
    Query = new EntityQueryExpression
    {
        Properties = entityProperties,
        Criteria = customFilter,
    }
};
```

This method also has the benefit of only retrieving what specific properties you need, which makes the request faster and the payload smaller. It's specifically designed for mobile where you want to only retrieve the Metadata you need, and what has changed since the last time you retrieved it, but it works nicely in a lot of scenarios.

Comment: Looks like what I need. I'm going to try that after weekend. Just one thing: What's the purpose of the `new MetadataFilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or)` line? What would happen if it was initialized with a `LogicalOperator.Or`?

Comment: Shouldn't be any different, this just happened to be the code I had around. Add long as you set it to Or you should be fine, it defaults to And if you don't set it.

Comment: Oops, had a typo there: I meant to ask what would happen if it was initialized with a `LogicalOperator.And`?

Comment: Thought there might be a typo there :) In this case, it would return nothing, because there's no way for an entity to have a logical name of both account and contact.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest`. Sample below:

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest retrieveAllEntityRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest
{
RetrieveAsIfPublished = true,
EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes
};
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse retrieveAllEntityResponse = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(retrieveAllEntityRequest);
```

CRM SDK has all or one-by-one approach only.

You have to keep your list of entities ready & issue the `RetrieveEntityRequest` for each item.

Comment: But it would retrieve every exisitng entity, wouldn't it? I'd like to know if it's possible to do this for specified entities.

Comment: Then you may need to keep the list & iterate to pull it using RetreiveEntityRequest.